# MeteorJs: How to place javascript files at the end of body in layout

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am newbie to MeteorJs. Right now i have installed Iron-route. When I open the source code of web page. I saw meteor injected all JavaScript files and coding in `<head>` tag. My question is that, in MeteorJs or Blaze, is it possible to place this JavaScript coding and files at the end of file ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you want to place the JS files and script tags at the bottom of your page because you want these to be loaded LAST (aka after the DOM has been completely loaded).

Say that on a normal html file you have these scripts at the bottom:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/slider_revolution.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/more-animations.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/animations.js"></script>
```

These will be loaded only after every line above it has been loaded.

In Meteor, what I do is something like this:

```
Template.templateName.rendered = function() {

  $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/slider_revolution.js"></script>');
  $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/animations.js"></script>');
  $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/more-animations.js"></script>');

}
```

So after the template has been rendered onto the page, Meteor will then go and append these scripts to the head. And then these scripts will load and run. This is roughly equivalent to having all the files load only after every other line has been loaded.

Comment: but meteor load the files in assets folder automatically how to avoid this?

Comment: @Ankita Meteor does not load files in assets automatically, assuming it's in `/public/assets`. You have to tell it when to load it. That's the point of the `/public` folder.

Comment: Actually I am new to meteor.Now I have understood the folder structure.

Comment: I had a similar issue with a jquery CDN and the above approach solved my probelm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something to inject script code at the end of the file. Although i'm not sure of the reasoning for this?

Meteor usually renders pages on the client side, so you would achieve the same thing whether you put the files in `<head></head>` or just before `</body>`

You can either put your code in `<head>..</head>` or inject it using code like this (probably in a Meteor.startup or when you know your body has been drawn):

```
var my_awesome_script = document.createElement('script');
my_awesome_script.setAttribute('src','http://example.com/site.js');
document.body.appendChild(my_awesome_script);
```

In Meteor when you do this if you decide to put it just before the end of `</body>` everything is rendered on the client side so once you add it you would not have to add it again (all the pages are rendered on the client as they are needed) so you wouldn't do it for one page as you would with PHP or other server side rendered pages.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to include them in the Layout rendered function..this will include them only after the html is printed..and you can add event listeners which will react when something chages in your scripts